# Full page vertical slideshow like apple.com/iphone-5c/

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we make a http://www.apple.com/iphone-5c/ like webpage using jquery.

Would we have to use plugins or just the jquery api would be enough. I was thinking of using '.scroll()'.

But then we cannot really specify which direction the user scrolls in. Any jquery plugin or any js library recommendation most welcome.

Comment: I would recommend you to use this: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#firstPage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're looking for

Jquery

```
            $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                   mode: 'vertical',
                    slideMargin: 5
             });
```

HTML

```
                  <ul class="bxslider">
                       <li><img src="/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" /></li>
                       <li><img src="/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
                       <li><img src="/images/730_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
                  </ul>
```

Comment: @Ricardo_Gonzales gave a good answer, I cant vote up but It has a lot of stuff that can be helpful for you.

Comment: Try this one: http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of jquery plugin. [here](http://www.desiznworld.com/2013/07/free-jquery-parallax-scrolling-plugins.html) there's a list with some of them. Scrollrama should help you